# join several files with "almost" different headers

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I'm trying to join several files, which look like below

```
file1

DATE;BAL_RO,ET-CAP,EXT_EA16;LRW_RT,AY-LME;
2014M01;AZ;PO; 
2013M12;WT;UF;       

file2

DATE;WALU-TF,TZ-AN;BAL_OP,WZ-CPI,WXZ-JUM;
2014M02;BA;LA; 
2014M01;BR;ON;
```

I'm trying to merge them to have the following results

```
DATE;WALU-TF,TZ-AN;BAL_OP,WZ-CPI,WXZ-JUM;BAL_RO,ET-CAP,EXT_EA16;LRW_RT,AY-LME;
2014M02;BA;LA; 
2014M01;BR;ON;AZ;PO;  
2013M12       WT;UF;
```

or

```
DATE;WALU-TF,TZ-AN;BAL_OP,WZ-CPI,WXZ-JUM;BAL_RO,ET-CAP,EXT_EA16;LRW_RT,AY-LME;
2014M02;BA;LA;; 
2014M01;BR;ON;AZ;PO;  
2013M12;;WT;UF;
```

I tried `join` but it says `filenameX is not sorted:`

If you have any ideas, they are welcomed.

Best.

Comment: I was thinking of adding an empty line in `file1` but I would still have trouble to do a `join` with file 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will this work for you:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"}
NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0;next}
{$0=($1 in a)?a[$1] $2 FS $3:$0; delete a[$1]}1;END{for(x in a) print a[x]}' file2 file1
DATE;WALU-TF,TZ-AN;BAL_OP,WZ-CPI,WXZ-JUM;BAL_RO,ET-CAP,EXT_EA16;LRW_RT,AY-LME
2014M01;BR;ON;AZ;PO
2013M12;WT;UF;
2014M02;BA;LA;
```

- We set the field separators (Input and Output) to `;`
- We scan the first file and create an array indexed at column 1 and assign it value of entire line
- Once the first file is completed, we start reading the second file. If the first column is present in our array, we append  the current line to the line stored in array. We delete the array item.
- Once all lines of second file are processed, we loop through the array to see if there are any items left. If so we print them.

Comment: OMG! 

Can you explain, Jaypal, please? 

I need to buy that awk book I've promised myself to buy a month ago as I've been paid today.

Comment: @AndyK Added the explanation. Hope that helps!

Comment: Question Jaypal: Can it work if the files have a lot of headers , each of them, and not only 3 of them as I've shown in the example.

Comment: @AndyK It should. If you have 4 or 5 headers you can pad them as I have shown above. If you have 100s then it would be tedious and would require a different approach. Using `for loop` to iterate over all fields or `sub()` to remove first field etc

Answer (score 0):

Bash has this wonderful feature that allows to sort both files in-line:

```
$ join -t ';' -a 1 -a 2 -o 0 1.2 1.3 2.2 2.3 <(sort -n file1 ) <(sort -n file2)
DATE;BAL_RO,ET-CAP,EXT_EA16;LRW_RT,AY-LME;WALU-TF,TZ-AN;BAL_OP,WZ-CPI,WXZ-JUM
2013M12;WT;UF;;
2014M01;AZ;PO;BR;ON
2014M02;;;BA;LA
```

Explanation:

`-t ';'`: use `;` as both input and output separator.

`-a 1 -a 2`: also print unpairable lines from both file1 and file2.

`-o 0 1.2 1.3 2.2 2.3`: each line is formatted as `0` (the join field), `1.2` (2nd field of `file1`), `1.3` (3rd field of `file1`), etcetera.

`<(sort -n file1)`: numeric sort `file1` via bash process substitution.

`<(sort -n file2)`: numeric sort `file2` via bash process substitution.

For details on bash process substitution, see: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html.

Comment: Hi Gerrit, thanks for answering. Can you explain a bit more , please?

Can I say that 1.2 1.3 2.2 2.3 are the columns name? If yes, does it mean the input have to be typed manually?

Cheers.

Comment: Cheers Gerrit. It helps.

Comment: I think I can automate that. It will be a bit more tricky on the columns part but still doable.

Comment: I tried to leave out the `-o ...` option. According to the manual it should give the desired result: `Default FORMAT outputs the join field, the remaining fields from FILE1, the remaining fields from  FILE2,`, but sadly this does not work: the join field is omitted from the result :-( Perhaps a bug in `join`.